# Setting up private access to my jenkins server using vpn

Tags: azure, jenkins, continuous-integration, cloud, vpn

I have windows 10 VM in azure cloud and a localhost Jenkins server hosted in my PC! 
The question is how can I access the Jenkins server from the VM using VPN . 
I googled this issue but I can't find a solution !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a local Jenkins server, and you are RDPing into an Azure VM, and then want to access the local Jenkins server from the VM?

If this is the case, you will need network connectivity from your Azure VM to your local computer. To do this, you will have 2 options:

1. open up your local jenkins server to the internet (not advised for security reasons) by forwarding the port on your local router.
2. Create a VPN (P2S or S2S) to your Azure VNET on your local computer. Then you should be able to connect from the VM to your internal IP.

The RDP connection will not give any access from your VM back to your computer, so a  better way to think about this is just how you can access the site on your local computer from your VM.